# Make 2 Ajax requests at the same time?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to make a ajax request to get some data from a database, and then send that data to another file which will return another result. Doesn't seem to work, the first Ajax request works fine, but then the second one which is triggered when the first returns the result, does nothing.

```
var http = getHTTPObject();
    var http2 = getHTTPObject();
    ids = fetchSelection().toString();

    //Make button animate, visual aid that it is working
    obj.src = "http://localhost/nightclub_photography/images/buttons/"+dir+"_animated.gif";

    http.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            http2.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
                if (http2.readyState == 4 && http2.status == 200)
                {
                    alert("hello");
                }
            }
            http2.open("GET", "http://localhost/nightclub_photography/net/test2.aspx");
            http2.send();
        }
    }
    http.open("GET", "http://localhost/nightclub_photography/asp/returnDatabaseData.asp?ids="+ids);
    http.send();
```

Comment: what happens if you put the alert outside the `if` statement in `http2.onreadystatechange = function()`?

Comment: Have you loaded `test2.aspx` into your browser directly to make sure it executes and returns as planned?

Comment: Could you also post the code for the getHTTPObject function?

Comment: How are you verifying that the first request completes? Does `http2.onreadystatechange` ever fire at all? It may be encountering an error, which you might see by logging the value of `http2.readyState` each time it fires.

Comment: Avoid the js callback hell and use JQuery promises which makes life easier and easiert ro read your code. http://jsfiddle.net/staar2/P85U3/

Comment: I don't want to use JQuery, prefer to do it all myself. Learn more.

Answer (score 1):

test.aspx was returning an error as I forgot to pass on the URL variables which it was looking for. Silly me, thanks guys!

Comment: Accept your own answer so this question is flagged as answered (and you can earn a badge :-) )